# Werid PHP behaviour when comparing types

Tags: php, if-statement, compare

I have following code:

```
var_dump($attr['value']);
if ($attr['value'] != 0 && $attr['value'] != null) {
    echo $attr['value'];
    $i++;
}
```

The problem is that dump tells me the $attr['value'] is 8 characters long string but the if condition fails and the code doesn't show me the value of $attr['value'] inside the if block. Is the condition wrong? I don't want to check the length of the string cause sometimes it can be also 1 character long string.

Comment: Can you please paste the value of $attr and $attr ['value'] from the var_dump so we can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that any non-numeric string will be converted to `0` when compared to integer unless you use the `===` operator.

Try this:

```
var_dump('a' == 0);   // true
var_dump('a' === 0);  // false
```

The solution you are searching for is:

```
if(isset($attr['value']) && !empty($attr['value'])) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition :

```
if ($attr['value'] != 0)
```

Verifies if $attr['value'] **CONTAINS** 0, this is NOT the length of the string.

If you want to verify the string length, modify your code to this :

```
var_dump($attr['value']);
if (strlen($attr['value']) != 0 && $attr['value'] != null) 
{
    echo $attr['value'];
    $i++;
}
```

strlen($variable) will verify the length of the string :

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strlen.php

It seems that you are simply checking if the variable is set, in that case, you could simplify your code to this :

```
var_dump($attr['value']);
if ($attr['value']) 
{
    echo $attr['value'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: That was totally correct, didn't notice that I wanted to check the length of the string.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(!empty($attr['value'])){
```